# Weighted Average Proof

Tags: probability, statistics

Been stuck on this for a while now, seems pretty straightforward but can't seem to prove it.

Given $\mu$ is a weighted average of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ such that $\mu = x_1\mu_1 + x_2\mu_2$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive real numbers and $x_1 + x_2 = 1$, prove that $\mu$ must lie between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.

And then in the more general case suppose $\mu = x_1\mu_1 + x_2\mu_2 + \cdots + x_n\mu_n$ where again the $x_i$'s are positive and $\sum x_i = 1$, prove that $\mu$ must lie between the smallest and largest of the $\mu_i$'s.

Comment: Another way to look at this is to think of $\mu$ as defining a linear programming problem over a simplex constraint, whose optimum must occur at extreme points (corresponding to max/min of the $\mu_i$s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get you started.

Suppose without loss of generality that $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2$. Then we have that
$$ \mu = x_1\mu_1 + x_2\mu_2 \leq (x_1 + x_2)\mu_2 = \mu_2.$$
Each other subcomponent of the proof looks extremely similar to this line.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Without loss of generality assume that $\mu_1\le\mu_2$. Then

$$\mu=x_1\mu_1+x_2\mu_2=x_1\mu_1+x_2\big(\mu_1+(\mu_2-\mu_1)\big)=(x_1+x_2)\mu_1+\ldots$$

Finish this off, and it gives you half of what you want, and a similar idea applied to $\mu_2$ gets you the other hald.

Then try to apply the basic idea to the general case.